# Скачивание видео с ВК

Tags: html, vkontakte-api

Есть видео полученное через VK API, например [это](https://cs1-67v4.vkuservideo.net/p10/6e1db8cea984.480.mp4?extra=uEKCMVf1fJ9E1qOjtAMdTb8mbs3xubJvAZzuB2fE7qvRHnD59dJlnqCwjUEYsc0wUbWZ3XYepjX8VkPWHIZGBWr9SPWDHiLdR1u7dIZ5BHEUrTUZGBJNeGYp7EKCQYbGLNLKU4aLlMp-LWfc0p5UA7Y05A). Как теперь по нажатию скачать его?

Сейчас мой прогресс выглядит так:

```
<a href="<ссылка>" download>
    <button>скачать</button>
</a>
```

Но,после нажатия, открывается просто ссылка с видео, вместо скачивания

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я до сих пор не разобрался в чем проблема того, переходя по ссылке, видео не скачивается, но, сделав запрос на эту же ссылку при помощи библиотеки [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/#), в ЯП `Python`, видео скачалось.

```
import requests

req = requests.get('<ссылка на видео>')

with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as video:
    video.write(req.content)
```

Так-же, у меня получилось начать скачивание, 'отрубив' от ссылки `extra` часть:

`https://cs1-67v4.vkuservideo.net/p10/1b4b195eeb27.480.mp4`